# Using getOrElse to return default value

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a hash

```
var unigram = new HashMap[String, Int]
```

I want to get the value of an element from the hash or in case the element doesn't exist, I want to get `0`.

So I am trying to use `getOrElse` like this:

```
unigram("a") getOrElse 0
```

However, I get: `"Cannot resolve symbol."`

How am I using it incorrectly?
What can I use instead of it?

Comment: `unigram.getOrElse("a", 0)` is what you want, here. See the [relevant section of the API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.Map@getOrElse(key:A,default:=>B):B).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `unigram getOrElse("a",0)`
You can't just call the `apply` method and then run `getOrElse`on it, since `apply` already retrieves the value.

For reference if you call `unigram("a")`, it's actually calling the `apply`method `unigram.apply("a")` which just returns the element.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do `val unigram = Map("foo" -> 1) withDefault(_ => 0)`
Now `ungram("bar")` returns 0.